# Adding Scroller to the linear layout inside relative layout not working

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to give a scroll view for a linear layout inside a relative layout , actually the linear layout is used to inflate textview and buttons but after doing changes also iam not getting the scroller please help me  This is my xml file pleas e help me iam new to android

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search item" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Qty"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_to_bill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/billshow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_bill"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_bill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/billshow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/billshow"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submit_bill"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , thank you all anyways

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Search item" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Qty"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_to_bill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Add"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_bill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/submit_bill"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/billshow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="278dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_bill"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/submit_bill"
    android:text="Price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Qty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Item"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```